# Internet explorer keeps alerting with location.reload(); Data in page from previous form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my site the user selects to view a ticket from a list in a table. When the user selects the ticket, the ticket number is posted to the next page which displays all of the data associated with said ticket. On that same page is various options to modify the ticket. One example is you can log whether 911 responded or not. The user clicks a link which executes this code:

```
$("#submitEmergCall").click(function(){
    ticket_num = $("#ticket_num").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'AJAX/outage_911.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {ticket_num: ticket_num},

        success: function(){ 
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
});
```

On all browsers this code executes perfectly, but on internet explorer their is a popup "To display the webpage again..." I have tried using:

window.location.href = window.location.href;

but when it reloads the page the ticket number is not known so it does not show the correct data.

Is there a way to correct this issue or make these calls in a better way?

Comment: use GET instead of POST? (when the user selects the ticket)

Comment: If possible, don't `reload` the page. Just redraw what you need on the page.